# usb_claim_interface error -6

Tags: usb, usb-device

I've installed rtl-sdr on a Raspberry Pi. Now, since I'm going to use it remotely, I want to use Stephen Blinick's ring buffer rewrite of rtl_tcp as detailed here: https://www.rtl-sdr.com/significantly-improving-rtl_tcps-performance-with-ring-buffers/

Unfortunately, I started out by installing rtl-sdr. Now, when I run my local copy of Stephen's rtl-sdr, I get

```
Kernel driver is active, or device is claimed by second instance of librtlsdr.
In the first case, please either detach or blacklist the kernel module (dvb_usb_rtl28xxu), or enable automatic detaching at compile time.

usb_claim_interface error -6
Failed to open rtlsdr device #0.
```

I've tried removing the official rtl-sdr, but that didn't change anything.

What does it mean that the device is claimed by a second instance of librtlsdr? How do I control, which instance of librtlsdr can claim the device?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su
apt-get install gedit
sudo gedit ban-rtl.conf
```

Type this line in the text file you created:

```
blacklist dvb_usb_rtl28xxu
```

Save the file and reboot the machine. Now if you type `rtl_test -t` again in the terminal hopefully you will not see the previous error